# Passing NSArray to UITable View instead of UILabel

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, nsarray

I have a Javascript Array that has been pushed to Objective-C via an `NSArray`. I am able to get this array to show up via a `UILabel` with this code:

```
NSString *testArrayString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testString"];
NSArray *testArray = [testArrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSLog(@"%@", testArray);


self->myLabel.text = [testArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Instead of a `UILabel`, if I want this to work with a `UITableView`, how could I go about doing so?

Comment: Do you mean you want each component to be in a separate cell? Or you want the whole string in one cell?

Comment: Yes, each component in a separate cell. So the UITableView would have to count how many cells to make based on whats in the array in my Javascript, right?

Comment: okay here goes nothing... From the array you can decide how many rows your table needs, and for each cell just set the cell.textLabel.text = testArray[indexpath.row]; and that should work. but other than that u need to learn how tableview works. because if you knew you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Thank You, But I want the Table view to count how many cells are needed based on the the number of strings in the array in my javascript.

Comment: Lemme get this straight -- you want to use a table view, but you don't want to learn how to use one??

Comment: I know how to use a table view. I don't know how to incorporate a javascript array that has been converted to a NSArray in a table view.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it was a JS array or Fortran.  Once it's into an NSArray that's what you have.  If you know how to use a table view you know how to use an NSArray to build the view (since 95% of table views are based on an NSArray).

Comment: Yes, But for some reason, the number of cells don't count. There is only one cell that wants to show up and only one item in my array show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this blog post saved in my drafts folder for awhile. Your question made me remember it and publish the post:

http://appsylvania.com/post/59049992843/introduction-to-uitableview

I also answered a similar question here the other day:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322362/186911

Good luck to you sir.

Comment: My pleasure. We were all noobs once. I'm trying to learn more about what it takes to teach some of the basic stuff. I can explain it all day but whether or not it makes sense on the other end, that's the hard part

Answer (score 2):

A.  Make your testArray either an iVar or property

B.  Assuming what you have already created an tableView

C.  Implement the following data source for [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return testArray.count;  //for property use self.testArray.count instead
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [testArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: How can I make my testArray a iVar or Property? I couldn't really find anything online.

Comment: @MinaDawoud - You don't know how to define an Objective-C ivar or property??

Comment: Is it the same as defining a Boolean?

Comment: @MinaDawoud Yeah, of course you `know how to use a table view` but cannot define a property or ivar? :O You should learn the language first and after that the frameworks ... btw there is plenty of stuff online!